# React Native not passing data through navigation param

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass some data when navigating to another screen, but it's not working. It navigates to the screen but the data is undefined.

I have this button on the 'Produto' Screen:

```
onPress={() => {
  props.navigation.navigate("Login", {
    test: "This is just a test"
  });
}}
```

Login Screen:

```
const LoginScreen = props => {    
  const test = props.navigation.getParam("test");
  console.log(test);
```

test is undefined.

My Navigator (I removed imports and other stuff from this snippet):

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Produto: ProdutoScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);

const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: LoginScreen
  }
);

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: MainNavigator
    },
    Login: {
      screen: LoginNavigator
    }
  }
);

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Start: StartScreen,
  Home: DrawerNavigator
});
```

Comment: Have you ever used react-router? It might make this task easier. 

I am not familiar with SwitchNavigator. Not sure how props are passed

Answer (score 0):

Just update the line where you are trying to access the param. Like this,

```
const LoginScreen = props => {    
  const test = props.navigation.state.params.test;
  console.log(test);
}
```

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')

Comment: Without 'this': undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.state.params.test')

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Produto: ProdutoScreen,
    Login: LoginScreen,     //this will resolve your issue
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);
```